# Select dup indices into a nested internal table in each table row?

Tags: types, duplicates, abap, internal-tables

I have the following code to find the duplicates in an itab:

```
TYPES: BEGIN OF ty_duplicates,
  id type i,
  END OF ty_duplicates.
TYPES _duplicates type STANDARD TABLE OF ty_duplicates WITH NON-UNIQUE DEFAULT KEY.

DATA(table_with_duplicates) = VALUE _duplicates( ( id = 1 ) ( id = 2 ) ( id = 1 ) ( id = 3 ) ( id = 3 ) ).

DATA(duplicates) = VALUE string_table( FOR GROUPS <group> OF <line> IN table_with_duplicates
GROUP BY ( id = <line>-id size = GROUP SIZE )
    ( LINES OF COND #( WHEN <group>-size > 1 THEN VALUE string_table( (
concat_lines_of(
    table = VALUE string_table(
            FOR <line2> IN GROUP <group> INDEX INTO idx ( |{ idx }| ) )
    sep   = ',' ) ) ) ) ) ).

  cl_demo_output=>display_data(
    EXPORTING
      value = duplicates
  ).
```

Sadly with this code, the indices of the duplicates get written into one line as a string.

How would I go on to change this code so I get instead a nested table inside each line, where each index is a separate line in it? So the result would look similar to this:

```
DATA(indices) = VALUE #( 
( ( index1 ) ( index2 ) ) (  ( index1 ) ( index2 ) )  "and so on..
).
```

Comment: Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), including the types, data and example data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case we need to have a kind of a nested table type, i.e. table inside a table, so start with defining an appropriate type for it. I named it **ty_t_string_table**, so it is a table, where each element is a table of type string_table:

```
TYPES: ty_t_string_table TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF string_table 
                         WITH NON-UNIQUE DEFAULT KEY.
```

Afterwards we do not need to make a concatenation of the ids inside a table element, but to create the table itself. The code for it:

```
  DATA(duplicates) = VALUE ty_t_string_table(
    FOR GROUPS <group> OF <line> IN table_with_duplicates
    GROUP BY ( id = <line>-id size = GROUP SIZE )
    ( LINES OF COND #( WHEN <group>-size > 1 THEN VALUE #(

      ( VALUE #( FOR <line2> IN GROUP <group> INDEX INTO idx ( |{ idx }| ) ) )

    ) ) )
  ).
```

It is enough to specify the type *ty_t_string_table* `VALUE ty_t_string_table(` only by the fist value declaration, inside we do not need to mention types  again and just use `#(`, the types of a table and its component would be automatically derived.

Note that displaying nested tables is not supported by `cl_demo_output=>display_data`, so set a breakpoint to check the result.

[image: ty_t_string_table]
[image: string_table]
[image: string_table]

Comment: Seeing your solution made be metaphorically bang my head against the wall considering how close I was to that exact solution at one point :D. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes, it happens from time to time to everyone :) So we are here to help each other when it happens.